# Intellisense not updating on a reference library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I have a C# application that references a C# library, they are both in the same solution, and were added using the Add Reference/Project tab.

When I change something (Add/Remove a member) in a class in the library, the intellisence in the C# application doesn't get updated.  Everything compiles find, but I don't see the new members that were recently added.

I've tried things like rebuild all but that didn't do it.  The only fix I have for it right now is to remove the reference, and add it again.  That updates the intellisense information.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you adding the reference to the project or a compiled DLL?

Comment: To the project. I right click on project, select Add Reference..., select the Projects tab, and select the project.

Comment: In your build configuration, is your referenced project set to build?

Comment: Yes. I also checked the Project Dependencies dialog to make sure the dependencies where setup correctly.

Comment: Not exactly a fix, but does closing the solution and then re-opening it update the intellisense for you?

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but it came up when I searched for having the exact same issue. I eventually resolved the problem by right clicking on the c# library and selecting clean then building the class library again. Now changes are updating intellisense normally.